# AWS Machine Learning predication by three fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-machine-learning

i have created a model in AWS

contains Sales records by date

for example

Type: Sale,Time:2016-08-01,Success:1 (1 is a boolean)

i want to predict how much Sales will be after 1 month from the latest date (2016-08-01)

which means a combo of Type=Sale AND Time >2016-08-01 and Success=1

any idea how to achieve this

thank u

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate your data to a wider array of attributes to be able to use Amazon ML for such predictions. You can use different level of aggregation, for example daily, weekly and monthly.

You should also add any relevant information for the items that you are selling. For example, if you are selling umbrellas, you should add information about the amount of rain on that day, or if you are selling flowers, you should add information about day of the week or proximity to holidays, when people are buying more flowers.